# X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) when launching Spyder on GNOME

Tags: qt, anaconda, spyder

sorry if this question is not as detailed and focused as it should be.
I am a Linux user (so no admin privileges of any sort) and just installed Anaconda3 from [here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) and followed the instructions.

**Note** that my Linux machine is *not* connected to the internet, so I had to transfer the file through other means and just run `bash Anaconda...` as instructed in the Continuum site.

I have then succesfully launched `IPython` and tried to plot inline, without problems. However, when I tried to use plotting in windows, I got this kind of output from the terminal:

```
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9   Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
```

And the created graph window was just blank.

I then tried to start `Spyder` and basically saw the same behaviour: **a lot** of those errors reported above, and the `Spyder` window just popped up blank.

Google search for the error gives results reported for `Qt`, which makes sense since when plotting "offline" (as opposed to `inline`) then `QtAgg` is used.

However, I have no clue as to where to look for the version of these libs, how to install/compile new ones, whether that is really the issue or not. I am just to ignorant about Linux.

Anybody can hint on what to look for and how to try to debug this behaviour?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error. What worked for me is to add this line in /etc/environment.

*sudo nano /etc/environment*

Add this line
*QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1*

Source : https://github.com/P0cL4bs/WiFi-Pumpkin/issues/53#issuecomment-309120875

Note that in my case the fix didn't take effect until I rebooted my machine.

Answer (score 3):

you may simply run on the terminal:

export QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error, so I'll tell you what worked for me.

I think it is a permissions issue, based on the following:
I was logged in through a VNC server window through my account, but within the VNC server was setting up a user profile for "user2".  In a 'user2' console I installed anaconda in user2's directory.  When I typed spyder in the user2 console, I got the exact error you describe.  I guessed the VNC desktop didn't like user2 trying to open a window on user1's profile.  I then logged out of my VNC server window, logged into the user2 vnc server window, and in a console typed 'spyder' and it opened perfectly.
I think for some reason it is trying to open but is installed in a directory that you don't have permissions for or trying to open in a window that you don't have access to.